# Sort a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying sort a predetermined range of cells from a UserForm (let's say A1:A5) using an array size as an integer, and the array itself. I've checked out 20+ links without finding a solution.

The code below successfully gets the values of the array (for my testing there are five doubles), pastes them into the worksheet `sheetOperations` (I always use code-targeted sheets to minimize issues). So the sheet targeting works, and the looping through the array and getting the values works.

Sorting the range (A1:A5) hasn't been successful. I've tried a variety of code. I'm trying to get A1 to A5 (on that specific worksheet) to list the previous values in the range in descending order - when I run this code (I tried ascending, descending) it has given me various errors such 1004, etc.

If A1:A5 is {1,3,2, 4, 6}, I want it to make A1:A5 {6,4,2,3,1}.

```
Sub timeStampStorePart2(ByRef doubleArray() As Double, ByVal size As Integer)


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsFound2 As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If StrComp(ws.CodeName, "sheetOperations", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Set wsFound2 = ws
        'MsgBox ("Found")
    End If
Next ws

Dim loopInt As Integer

Dim arrayInt As Integer
Dim rangeAddress As String

arrayInt = 0
loopInt = 1

For loopInt = 1 To size
        rangeAddress = "A" & loopInt
        wsFound2.Range(rangeAddress).Value = doubleArray(arrayInt)
        arrayInt = arrayInt + 1
Next loopInt


'rangeAddress = "A1:" & rangeAddress
'MsgBox (rangeAddress)
'Dim dataRange As Range
'Set dataRange = wsFound2.Range(rangeAddress)
wsFound2.Range("A1:A5").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo


End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: If you're using the sheet codename, then I'm not sure why you're looping `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`. Just use the code name.

Comment: that group of code i've been using frequently after seeing somewhere else on stack exchange, it's to make sure the exact worksheet is targeted. Could you show me how you would do it?

Comment: `sheetOperations.Range("A1:A5")` - just use the code name directly.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, here is a pretty simple code that sorts the range you describe using an array...

*slightly updated to meet the integer requirement.*

```
Sub sortStuff()
Const addr As String = "A1:A6"
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ActiveSheet 'or whatever the sheet ID name is
Dim sRNG As Range: Set sRNG = WS.Range(addr)


'changed this from first answer to integer requirement and optimize code
ReDim aRay(1 To sRNG.Rows.Count, 1 To sRNG.Columns.Count) As Integer


Dim x As Long, y As Long
For x = LBound(aRay, 1) To UBound(aRay, 1)
    For y = LBound(aRay, 2) To UBound(aRay, 2)

    aRay(x, y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(sRNG.Columns(y), x)
    Next y
Next x

'Puts into excel
sRNG = aRay


End Sub
```